# Two Port Network

Tags: network

So I'm studying $S$ parameters for two port networks. I've seen some special cases like what happens if port 2 is short circuited or if port 2 is matched with port 1. I was wondering what happens if port 2 is open circuited? I think $V_2$- would be zero for this condition. Am I right?

$$V_{1}^{-} = S_{11}(V_{1}^{+})+S_{12}(V_{2}^{+})$$

$$V_{2}^{-} = S_{22}(V_{2}^{+})+S_{21}(V_{1}^{+})$$

Comment: hint: check the definition of the port waves (incident, reflected) expressed directly from the port voltages and currents, then note that in an open circuit the current is zero, therefore....

Comment: The reflected current from port 2 should be zero, if I write equation for incident and reflected waves,
b1=S11(a1)+S12(a2)
b2=S21(a1)+S22(a2)
this would mean b2=0, and S21(a1)=-S22(a2). Am I correct?

Comment: not the reflected current but THE current is zero in an open circuit; the answer of @xxx below is wrong, it should be $\Gamma = 1$

Comment: You're right so  Γ=1 would mean V2- = V2+. Also are you sure THE current is zero? It's a two port network. There's still a possibility for current to flow inside the network (e.g: RLC) even if there's no current at the output port. Basically no current at port 2 means no load is connected to the system, not that the system itself has no current,

Answer (score 0):

If you leave a port open that is the same thing as having an impedance $\infty$ which is the same as having $\Gamma = -1$, therefore $V^{-}=-V^{+}$. So in your case the condition imposed on the scattering matrix would be $V^{-}_2=-V^{+}_2$

If you plug that in to the equations above, isolate the $V_2$, and divide the equations you will obtain:

$$V_1^{-}= \Big(S_{11}-\frac{S_{21}S_{12}}{1+S_{22}} \Big) V_1^{+}$$

Where $S_{11}-\frac{S_{21}S_{12}}{1+S_{22}} $ is the reflection coefficent seen from port 1.

Notice for a general reflection coefficent at port 2; $\Gamma$ the relation would read:

$$V_1^{-}= \Big(S_{11}+\frac{\Gamma S_{21}S_{12}}{1+ \Gamma S_{22}} \Big) V_1^{+}$$

It is just in this case that $\Gamma = -1$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I initially thought that in open circuit both voltages at port 2 would be equal. But in David Pozar's book, this equality is applied for short circuit at port 2 so I thought that it can't be the same case for both open and short circuit

Comment: @JOHN you are absolutely correct, my initial answer ahd the wrong +/-, I have fixed it and added the general answer as well, sorry about that, the difference between the open and short case is a minus sign in the reflection coefficent